# How can I plot my R Squared value on my scatterplot using R?

Tags: r, plot, statistics, linear-regression

This seems a simple question, so I hope its a simple answer. I am plotting my points and fitting a linear model, which I can do OK. I then want to plot some summary statistics, for example the R Squared value, on the plot also. I can only seem to get the R Squared value at the command line.
Any advice; do I need to be looking at ggplot or anything else? Thanks in advance.

```
#Does the plot
plot(df$VAR1, df$VAR2)
#Adds the line
abline(lm(df$VAR2~df$VAR1), col="red")
#Shows stats on command line
summary(lm(df$VAR2~df$VAR1))
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can abuse `legend()` because it has the handy logical placement:

```
R> DF <- data.frame(VAR1=rnorm(100), VAR2=rnorm(100))
R> with(DF, plot(VAR1, VAR2))
R> abline(fit <- lm(VAR2 ~ VAR1, data=DF), col='red')
R> legend("topright", bty="n", legend=paste("R2 is", 
+         format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=4)))
```

Here `bty="n"` suppresses the box, and you need `format()` to shorten the display. Other `text()` is good, as are arguments `main=` and `sub=` to `plot()`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Seems to work, don't think I would have thought of that in a hurry!

Comment: Apologies - still getting used to how this all works. I think thats accepted now..

Comment: No apology needed. At some point each one of us was new here, and we're all learning together.

Answer (score 7):

The `text` function places text into the current plot, it is one option for adding the r-squared value to a plot.  Also look at the `grconvertX` and `grconvertY` functions for ways to find the location to place the text.

The `corner.label` and `emptyspace` functions in the `plotrix` package may also help.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative option. I'm already used to using legend so will stick with that for now.