# Creating legends that report R^2 correctly

Tags: r, format, legend, linear-regression

Apologies if this has been asked before; I couldn't locate a similar question besides this one ([How can I plot my R Squared value on my scatterplot using R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761410/how-can-i-plot-my-r-squared-value-on-my-scatterplot-using-r)). It was helpful in demonstrating the right way to call the R<sup>2</sup> value itself.

My problem is that I am unable to get the "R<sup>2</sup>" to display properly, i.e. with the 2 as a superscript.

Using this code, I get the correctly-formatted R<sup>2</sup>, but the value is on the next line.

```
x <- 1:100
y <- 1:100
fit <- lm(y~x)
plot(x, y)
abline(lm(y~x))
legend("topleft", c(expression(paste("R"^2, "=")), 
       format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, digits=3)))
```

If I put the `format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared` command within `paste` or `expression`, it (predictably) prints `format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared` in the legend.

How to I get around this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is to use `bquote`, and wrap any code that requires evaluation in `.()`, as suggested by @GGrothendieck [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-Math-expression-with-object-to-evaluate-td814939.html).

```
legend('topleft', bty='n',
       as.expression(bquote(R^2==.(format(summary(fit)$adj.r.squared, 
                                          digits=3)))))
```

See also Uwe's [Automation of Mathematical Annotation in Plots](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2002-3.pdf) R Help Desk.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you for answering and directing me to those helpful resources.